# Python: Design classes with same methods and different but equivalent

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, oop, design-patterns

I have an algorithm that performs the same tasks on different datasets. Essentially the methods are the same but the parameters are different. I'm trying to create classes for this but since I'm not familiar with OOP design principles I'm a bit confused how to do this.

Since, the algorithm is the same I figured I can create a common Class from which classes related to the two different datasets inherit from. For example,

```
class MyAlgorithm():
    def __init__(self, column1, column2):
        self.column1 = column1
        self.column2 = column2

    def step1():
        # do sth with dataset

    def step2():
        # do sth with result of step1()

class Dataset1Class(MyAlgorithm):
    def __init__(self, dbconn, tablename='dataset2table'):
        self.dbconn = dbconn
        self.tablename = tablename

    def get_data(dbconn, tablename):
        # get data from database for one date
        (column1A, column1B) = data_query # not shown
        return column1A, column1B


class Dataset2Class(MyAlgorithm):
    def __init__(self, dbconn, tablename='dataset1table'):
        self.dbconn = dbconn
        self.tablename = tablename

    def get_data(dbconn, tablename):
        # get data from database for one date
        (column2X, column2Y) = data_query # not shown
        return column2X, column2Y
```

I'm simplifying it here a bit and the datasource is actually a database but I think this may not be the best way to do it. So, I wonder how an experienced Pythonista would do it. Is there another better way to do this? This code is part of a larger codebase and will eventually be called from a Celery worker process along with the rest of the data pipeline.

Comment: Certainly I wouldn't bother writing a method in a subclass that's identical to the superclass, but given that you don't show any difference in behaviour between any of the classes it's impossible to say whether this is a good idea or not. Could you give a less abstract example?

Comment: @jonrsharpe This is essentially a case of having the same method but different parameters. I did think about just sending different parameters to the same class but the prospect of doing a lot of if...elif...else didn't appeal to me as well. I was trying to follow the template method pattern here.

Comment: @sfactor: then you need to identify the differences between the data and how it's processed in your question. If you have subclasses with the same methods, but different parameters, then you'll probably need to handle them differently anyway due to the different function signatures. If the data is sufficiently similar you might be able to get away with using keyword arguments with compatible default values. But it really depends on the data.

Comment: @mhawke i'd like to abstract out the algorithm and be able to reuse that if say later on I have different datasets as well. Is it possible to use the base class method from the child classes without reimplementing and do their own processing from the result? I'm guessing I need to use the super() method.

Comment: @sfactor yes it's possible and `super` exactly how you'd do it. If it's the processing that varies between the classes, *show that!*

Answer (score 0):

Why not pass different datasets to your algorithms class, instead of creating two classes for different algorithms.

```
class Algorithm:
  def __init__(self, dataset):
    self.dataset = dataset

  def method_1():
      """this is your algo implementation"""
      # perform action here on your dataset using self.dataset
```

Comment: oh I was writing ruby code right now, when I saw this question, quite embarrassed right now. Thanks for the changes @jonrsharpe

Answer (score 0):

The example, as shown, does not require inheritance at all.

Assuming that the data sets provide the same interface, e.g. a list of tuples, or a list of dictionaries, class `MyAlgorithm` is sufficient to process both data sets.

If the data formats differ, e.g. different number of fields, or the fields have different processing requirements due to different data types or semantics, then sub-classing and overriding the relevant processing methods seems a reasonable way to go.

Many examples of this strategy exist. One such from the Python 3 standard library is [`html.parser`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/html.parser.html?highlight=html.parser#module-html.parser) which provides the base class `HTMLParser` that you inherit from and override methods that you are interested in handling, such as when a new tag is seen, or a bit of data is read.

Comment: thanks for the answer and the reference to the html.parser implementation. yes I struggled with your reasoning as well but the two datasets have different parameters (although numeric) and if I had just the one class I would have to do a lot of if...elif...else depending on the dataset provided. the results would also be stored in different databases. that was my reason for trying to use this template pattern.

Comment: @sfactor: OK. See my comment to your main question.

Comment: @sfactor: As for storing the results in different databases, you can handle that by passing the database connection, or connection parameters, to the `__init__()` method of your class. But it totally depends on the schema as to whether that will be viable or not. If you want concrete help with your design I suggest that you post concrete details in your question, otherwise there's not enough information to advise properly.